# Node.js and npm pg for postgres error

Tags: node.js, npm

I am attempting to get the Postgesql client for node working with NPM. Using node v0.6.14 and receiving the following error:

> pg@0.5.4 install /Users/matt/Sites/node_test/node_modules/pg
>
> node-waf configure build || true

Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++

...

'configure' finished successfully (0.082s)

Waf: Entering directory '/Users/matt/Sites/node_test/node_modules/pg/build'

[1/2] cxx: src/binding.cc -> build/Release/src/binding_1.o

../src/binding.cc:3:25: error: node_events.h: No such file or directory

...

Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1):
{task: cxx binding.cc -> binding_1.o}
pg@0.5.4 ./node_modules/pg
└── generic-pool@1.0.6`

I have set the $NODE_PATH, and feel a bit stuck at this point, not quite knowing what is wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I was following the Heroku 'Getting Started with Node.js' article and that suggests using v0.5.4 of the pg package.

However, I am using version 0.6.x of Node and that so I was getting this same error you are.

I fixed it by changing my package.json file to specify v 0.6.15 of pg.

`"dependencies": {
  "pg": "0.6.15"
}`